# bounds for, $|L_{\tau}(s)|$, a Dirichlet searies associated with Ramanujan tau function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The Dirichlet searies associated with Ramanujan tau function is defined as:

\begin{equation}
L_{\tau}(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p \text{ }\mathrm{prime}}\frac{1}{1-\tau(p)p^{-s}+p^{11-2s}},\qquad \Re(s)>13/2.
\end{equation}

It is known that all the zeros of $L_{\tau}(s)$ are inside the critical strip $11/2<\Re(s)<13/2$ and most likely on the critical line $\Re(s)=6$.

Question:
What are the bounds of $|L_{\tau}(s)|$ when $11/2<\Re(s)<13/2$ and $\Im(s)$ goes to infinity?

Any comments are welcomed!
-mike

Comment: See Chapter 5 of Iwaniec and Kowalski. Basically, this is a Hecke eigenform of weight $k = 11$ and level $N = 1$, and standard zero-free regions are known. By the way, it is more normal (in analytic number theory, at least) to normalise the $L$-function so that its critical strip is $0 < \Re(s) < 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!